# Jump to View Controller after Login using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    birthdaylist=[[BirthdayList alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthdayList" bundle:nil];

    spinner=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.alpha=1.0;
    spinner.center=CGPointMake(130, 150);
    [spinner setHidden:YES];


    UIButton *PickFriendsButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [PickFriendsButton setFrame:(CGRectMake(100, 200, 150, 33))];
    [PickFriendsButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [PickFriendsButton setTitle:@"Pick Friends" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [PickFriendsButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [PickFriendsButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Politica" size:15]];
    [PickFriendsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PickFriends:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:PickFriendsButton];


    [super viewDidLoad];    

    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];


    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];


    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",
                            @"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",@"basic_info",
                            @"user_location",
                            @"user_birthday",
                            @"user_likes",
                            nil];


    loginview.readPermissions = permissions;

    }

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView

{
    // first get the buttons set for login mode


       NSLog(@"success");


    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {

        NSLog(@"TOKEN : %@",[[FBSession activeSession]accessTokenData]);


        FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];

        [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
        {
            NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data)
            {
                // NSLog(@"%@",friend);
                [delegate.friendsListArray addObject:friend];
                NSLog(@"%@:%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday],[friend id]);
            }
        }];
    }

    if ([delegate.friendsListArray count]!=0)

    {

        NSUserDefaults * standardDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        [standardDefaults setObject:delegate.friendsListArray forKey:@"FriendsListArray"];
        [standardDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];
        [standardDefaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"%@",[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"FriendsListArray"]);

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:birthdaylist animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Its cannot go to view controller.I Don't know.What is a Problem?Any have idea Please help me.Thanks to advance for your help.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening instead? Please tell us what you're asking -- don't make us guess. Also, it looks like a lot of the code that you posted isn't relevant to the problem -- if you can simplify the code to isolate the problem it'll help us help you. In fact, simplifying the problem is an excellent debugging technique -- it may help you spot the issue before you even ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

1. Check if your delegate.friendsListArray have any data in it. I see you log it. Let's provide that data here
2. I would remove all code in  if ([delegate.friendsListArray count]!=0) into friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler block . After for() ofcourse
3. if none of above not work for you. try this replace following code. then start to put other piece of code step by step.

> -(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
>
> ```
>    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
>       BirthdayList *birthdaylist=[[BirthdayList alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthdayList" bundle:nil];
>       [self.navigationController pushViewController:birthdaylist animated:YES];
>    }
> }
> ```

**more sample** as you comment try this. I hope you figure the rest of problem.

> -(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
>
> ```
>    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
>       FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location"];
>       [friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
>       {
>           NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
>           for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in data)
>           {
>                [delegate.friendsListArray addObject:friend];
>           }
>           if ([delegate.friendsListArray count] > 0) {
>               BirthdayList *birthdaylist=[[BirthdayList alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthdayList" bundle:nil];
>               [self.navigationController pushViewController:birthdaylist animated:YES];
>           } else {
>               UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Friend not found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
>               [alertView show];
>           }
>       }];
>
>    }
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hai,It go to another View.but,In this view,displays empty List.After come to this view,Retrieve the Details.

Comment: Well, then you are very close. put back code that get friend from FB API right after if here. good luck.

Comment: I dont understand.Please send via code.

Comment: see my "more sample" area.

Comment: Its go to another view first time.but,if i login to second time to same user.it have displayed this error.FBFriendPickerController[2069:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<BirthdayList: 0xa3ae050>)

Comment: You are almost there. I can't walk to you the success but i can tell you are very close this direction. key is that you have to clear view before pushViewController again.

Comment: Its Worked.I have one another doubt.I have Listed the FBFriendslist in Table view in Current Month order.But,Today Birthday Friends Details will display in First row(indexPath.row==0).Any idea Please help me.

Comment: let's give this one as answered, and you open new question. agree?

Comment: Agreed.I already asked this question.Link is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455766/display-the-today-date-in-indexpath-row-0-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment27122580_18455766

Comment: also accepted my answer?

Comment: ya.just now.Did u see this Link?

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you are asking. I would suggest try using this :-

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url;
```

It is a helper method that is used to provide an implementation for
 `[UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]` to properly resolve session state for
 the Facebook Login flow, specifically to support **app-switch login**.

e.g -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
// We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication to work.

return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I hope it resolves your issue. If you still have doubts, I will elaborate more.

Comment: I used this coding in openURL method return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];
is it correct of not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

First of all implement all the facebook sdk delegate methods in your app delegate.

```
- (IBAction)loginWithFacebookButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    IntubeAppDelegate *delegat = (IntubeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegat doLoginAndSwitch];
}
```

Now, in your appDelegate -

```
-(void) doLoginAndSwitch
{      
    [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil]; 
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                         allowLoginUI:YES
                                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                        [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                            state:state
                                                            error:error];

                                    }];
}

-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowPublishStreamPermission:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream", nil];

    [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error){
}];
     return YES;
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
              state:(FBSessionState)state
              error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if(!error)
            {
              //  NSLog(@"FBSessionStateOpen :- logged in");

                [self openSessionWithAllowPublishStreamPermission:YES];

              // Your code
            }
    }    
}
```

Also to switch back to your application -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I hope you would get what you desire now. :)

Comment: Displays Login Page.but,Which place can I added this code.BirthdayList *birthdaylist=[[BirthdayList alloc]initWithNibName:@"BirthdayList" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:birthdaylist animated:YES.

Comment: Sure.. you are on the right track.. Now.. you can put this code in the function `- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState)state
                      error:(NSError *)error` after the `[self openSessionWithAllowPublishStreamPermission:YES];` line where I already wrote above you can write your code.

Comment: i wrote this code.but cannot go to this view controller.This error occurred.'FBSession: It is not valid to reauthorize while a previous reauthorize call has not yet completed.'

Comment: I don't know how to accept ur question?Explain

Comment: You can do this if you want change the root view controller. UIViewController *viewController1;
 UINavigationController *viewController1Navigation;   viewController1 = [[BirthdayList alloc] nitWithNibName:@"BirthdayList" bundle:nil];
viewController1Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];                                        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1Navigation];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: You will see a tick mark next to my answer. Just click on that.

Comment: Sorry,i don't understand your coding.I am not use Tabbar controller.